# Import caffe in python in php code

Tags: php, python, linux, caffe

I have a test.php code

```
$b = system("python test.py", $a);
echo $a;
```

and the python test.py code

```
import caffe
print('!')
```

when I use php test.php in server by console, it is ok and print !0. But when I view the test.php in brower, it will has some errors and print 1. But I don't know what's wrong because the python run via system function.

Comment: 'it will has some errors' ... what are the errors ?

Comment: The system function can only return the error code 1, I don't know how to get the detail information about the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is based in permission: when you run test.php in console, this script is executed with your user, but when run test.php in web browser, this script is executed with webserver user (www-data probably).

I suggest to use a more simple py script:

> print('!')

in order to check that the problem is due to permission and nothing else.

What operating system are you using?